# Reset a counter at the start of every month

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

Im working on journal IDs in JavaScript format `JV001/1/2018`, `JV002/1/2018` and so on (for January). I need to reset the counter at the start of every month so that journals IDs for February will be `JV001/2/2018`, `JV002/2/2018` and so on.

The ID will be populated to an input element on page load. How can I use a single JavaScript function to do the counter, prototype.padStart and finally pass the value to an input element.

For my month and year I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDate(){
        var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
        var datestring = month + "/" + year;
        document.getElementById("referenceNumber").value = datestring;
    }
    getDate();
</script>
```

which is rendering as below:
[image]

Comment: Is this an application that will be used on one PC or do you have an application server? If so, which language environment?

Comment: Its running on Tomcat..Frontend is AngularJS Bootstrap and API in java..  i want to generate the IDs on the  client side however, using javascript..

Comment: If you want to generate them in JavaScript how will you manage that the generated values should be unique across multiple clients? You really need a server-sided implementation for dealing with this. Or is your application only used by one client?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check if today's date - a counter is == 0.

So you will start the counter at January 1st and it would be one.
Then you would get today's date and subtract it from the counter.

So, 1-1 = 0. Then as each day passes you would also increment the counter. Once `getDate()` passes 31, it would be 1, but the counter would be 32. So 1-32 != 0, and you reset the counter to match todays date.

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks .. would you mind articulating that in a javavascript routine.Trying to do the function but im missing a bit